# Basic Derivation using "7 rules"

Tags: logic

I'm just checking my work to make sure I'm going through this in a sane fashion:

$P\wedge Q, (P\wedge Q) \rightarrow (R\wedge S), (S\vee U) \rightarrow W \vdash W$

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline\ Scope &Step & Derivation&Rule\\ \hline1&(1)&P\wedge Q& A\\ \hline2&(2)&(P\wedge Q) \rightarrow (R\wedge S)&A
\\ \hline3&(3)&(S\vee U) \rightarrow W&A\\
\hline 1,2&(4)&R\wedge S
&1,2 \rightarrow E\\
\hline 1,2&(5)&S&4 \wedge E\\
\hline 1,2&(6)&S\vee U&5\vee I\\
\hline 1,2,3&(7)&W&3,6 \rightarrow E
\\ \hline \end{array}

Comment: Looks good to me (the logic, not the formatting).

Comment: Can I ask what book you're using?

Comment: Classical Logic and Its Rabbit-Holes: A First Course , Nelson P Lande,
ISBN-10: 1603849483.


Thanks so much for confirming the logic! Any tips on how I can do formatting easier on here?

Comment: Actually, I'm a latex and mathjax newbie, so I can't help with that. Besides, It's not really that bad -- don't worry about it.